# Not able to insert solar symbol using M[\u0298] in R

Tags: r

So far I am trying this.

```
fig2<-fig2 + ggtitle("Two channel data(Original Scale)") +
    theme(legend.position = c(0.2,0.8),
          plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
          axis.title = element_text(size=16),
          legend.text = element_text(size=16)) +
    xlab(expression(M[c] ~ 10^12 ~ M[\u0298]))
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You might try `bquote` in this case:

```
bquote(M[c] ~ 10^12 ~ M[.('\u0298')])
```

Whether this renders may be device-dependent. It works for me in RStudio:

```
plot(1, pch = '.')
text(1, 1, bquote(M[c] ~ 10^12 ~ M[.('\u0298')]))
dev.cur()
# RStudioGD 
#         2 
# RStudio.Version()$version
# [1] ‘1.4.324’
```

[image]

It also works on my `png`, `jpeg`, `bmp`, `tiff`, and `cairo_pdf` devices, but not on `pdf`:

```
pdf('test.pdf')
plot(1, pch = '.')
text(1, 1, bquote(M[c] ~ 10^12 ~ M[.('\u0298')]))
dev.off()
```

produces a bunch of warnings:

```
Warning messages:
1: In text.default(1, 1, bquote(M[c] ~ 10^12 ~ M[.("ʘ")])) :
  font metrics unknown for Unicode character U+0298
2: In text.default(1, 1, bquote(M[c] ~ 10^12 ~ M[.("ʘ")])) :
  font metrics unknown for Unicode character U+0298
3: In text.default(1, 1, bquote(M[c] ~ 10^12 ~ M[.("ʘ")])) :
  font metrics unknown for Unicode character U+0298
4: In text.default(1, 1, bquote(M[c] ~ 10^12 ~ M[.("ʘ")])) :
  font metrics unknown for Unicode character U+0298
5: In text.default(1, 1, bquote(M[c] ~ 10^12 ~ M[.("ʘ")])) :
  conversion failure on 'ʘ' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <ca>
6: In text.default(1, 1, bquote(M[c] ~ 10^12 ~ M[.("ʘ")])) :
  conversion failure on 'ʘ' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <98>
7: In text.default(1, 1, bquote(M[c] ~ 10^12 ~ M[.("ʘ")])) :
  conversion failure on 'ʘ' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <ca>
8: In text.default(1, 1, bquote(M[c] ~ 10^12 ~ M[.("ʘ")])) :
  conversion failure on 'ʘ' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <98>
```

And the wrong output:

[image]

Comment: Hi Thanks. But I have tried it gives me  M<U+0298>. Not sure why. :(

Comment: this will depend on your device. not all devices support all encodings